# Using Ordinal Encoding to encode custom values?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where features are categorical . Take a look at the attachment below.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxRM6.png)

The column labels are basically course codes and column values are grades earned so what if I want to ordinal encode the grades to custom values.

I want to encode grades with their respective Grade points (float) my university awards.
like A+ is 4.0 ,,A is 4.0 ,A- is 3.7,....

Does this encoding count as hot encoding and is this a better approach than ordinal encoding?

Comment: No this is not one-hot encoding, what is exactly your question/issue?

Comment: I want to train a regression model and apply some algorithm to predict CGPA but since the grades are categorical I want to encode them If I encode ordinally would it affect the accuracy of regression model? Or should I replace the Grade by Grade points whats the better approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not one hot encoding. It is not an ordinal encoder too, since you're using arbitrary floats to encode your labels.

That said, the approach is completely valid: you are encoding your categorical feature with an arbitrary function that maps categories to floats following a logic that makes sense in the world you are modeling. So, go on with this approach.

However, it doesn't mean this is the best approach . For sure it sounds like the first good option to consider but it's hard to ensure which is the best.